# ArangoDB memory overflow - is there no solution?

Tags: arangodb

When I perform AQL queries, I run into this error:

> Query: AQL: query would use more memory than allowed (while executing)

My dataset: 9 billion vertices, 19 billion edges

My cluster has three nodes, running Centos 7 with 32 GB RAM

I only hope that the query can be executed and will not be reported wrong. What configuration files can be modified to achieve the purpose? I am new to ArangoDB.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

Some back-of-the-envelope calculations suggest you will need to use the RocksDB engine:

```
(100 * 28 * 10^9) / (3 * (32 * 10^9)) => 29.17
```

See https://www.arangodb.com/why-arangodb/comparing-rocksdb-mmfiles-storage-engines/

Comment: I have already used rocksdb，You can tell me how you calculated this，thank you！

Comment: I just used your numbers and guessed an average for the number of bytes per (V+E).  If you are already using RocksDB and have enough disk space, then perhaps the cause is that ArangoDB has some memory requirements regarding the indexes it maintains.  What indexes have you defined?  It sounds like maybe you will have to reach out to ArangoDB more directly , e.g. at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues

Comment: I don't have a custom index，It's the default index of arangodb，Yes. My disk space is enough，I've already raised questions on GitHub, but the development team didn't solve me

Comment: Maybe the default indices require a lot of RAM?  Have you looked at https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/3806 ?  What is your issue #?